Add Hover Functionality Popup to Extended LightningDatatable
I'm a bit stumped here and hoping someone can help with this.  There's a lot to unwind but I wanted to include everything in this post.  I've got the following LWC setup to display contact roles related to an opportunity/quote.  I'm trying to get some sort of hover functionality setup.  I'd like to be able to hover over a contact's name from the list of contact roles and then display a popup displaying fields from the contact's record.  I hope this all makes sense, any guidance would be appreciated!
Here's the js file:
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getOpportunityContactRoles from '@salesforce/apex/CPQ_UpdateContactRoleFields.getOpportunityContactRoles';
import ROLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityContactRole.Role';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

const columns = [
    {label: "Contact", fieldName: "contactLink", type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'ContactName' }, target: '_blank'}},
    {label: 'Role', fieldName: 'Role', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
        placeholder: 'Choose Role', options: {fieldName: 'pickListOptions'},
        value: { fieldName: 'Role' },
        context: { fieldName: 'Id' } 
        }
    },
    {label: "Primary", fieldName: "IsPrimary", type: 'boolean', editable: true}
];

export default class ContactRolesComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    columns = columns;
    error;
    records;
    @track pickListOptions  = [];
    value = [];


    // fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "012000000000000AAA",
        fieldApiName: ROLE_FIELD
    })
    wirePickList(value) {
      this.dataToRefresh = value;
      const {data, error} = value;
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            this.queryOppContactRoles();
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    queryOppContactRoles(){
      getOpportunityContactRoles({recordId: this.recordId})
      .then((result) => {
            this.records = result.map((row) => {
              return {
                ...row,
                    'ContactName': row.Contact.FirstName +' ' + row.Contact.LastName,
                    'contactLink': '/' + row.ContactId,
                    'Role': row.Role,
                    'IsPrimary': row.IsPrimary,
                    'pickListOptions': this.pickListOptions
              }
            });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('got here');
      console.log(error);

        this.error = error;
    });
}
}

Here's the html file:
<template>
    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">
        <c-contact-custom-table
                  key-field="Id"
                  data={records}
                  columns={columns}
                  draft-values={draftValues}
                  oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                  onsave={handleSave}
                  oncancel={handleCancel}
                  onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}
          >
          </c-contact-custom-table>
    </div>
  </template>

In the html file, you can see I'm referencing a custom type/extended LightningDatatable (contactCustomTable).  This is because I'm including the Role picklist field inside of the table.  Here's the js file for the extended LightningDatable component:
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import picklistColumn from './picklistColumn.html';
import picklistStatic from './picklistStatic.html'

export default class ContactCustomTable extends LightningDatatable{
    static customTypes = {
        picklistColumn: {
            template: picklistStatic,
            editTemplate: picklistColumn,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant','name']
        }
    };
}

Here's the html for the extended LightningDatatable component:
<template>
    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">
        <c-contact-custom-table
                  key-field="Id"
                  data={records}
                  columns={columns}
                  draft-values={draftValues}
                  oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                  onsave={handleSave}
                  oncancel={handleCancel}
                  onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}
          >
          </c-contact-custom-table>
    </div>
  </template>

Within the contactCustomTable js file, I'm importing two additional html files.  Here's the imported picklistColumn html file:
<template>
    <!-- data-inputable="true"-->
    <c-data-table-picklist
            data-inputable="true"
            label={typeAttributes.label}
            value={editedValue}
            placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
            options={typeAttributes.options}
            context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-data-table-picklist>

</template>

And here's the imported picklistStatic html file:
<template>
    <div>{typeAttributes.value}</div>
</template>

And lastly, here's the dataTablePicklist lwc js and html files.  This lwc is referenced inside of the picklistColumn html file:
import {LightningElement,api} from 'lwc';

export default class DataTablePicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api context;
    _options;
    _value;

    @api
    get options() {
        return this._options
    }
    set options(value) {
        if (value) {
            this._options = Object.values(value);
        }
    }

    @api
    get value() {
        return this._value
    }
    set value(value) {
        if (value) {
            this._value = value;
        }
    }

    @api
    get validity() {
        return this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').validity;
    }
    @api
    showHelpMessageIfInvalid() {
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
    }
    @api
    focus() {
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').focus();
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        try {
            this._value = event.detail.value;
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="picklist"
                        label={label}
                        value={_value}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        options={_options}
                        onfocus={focus}
                        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>


You can use the lightning tooltip or create a custom popover component that can be triggered on mouseover events.

Thanks @TusharJadav but I don't think either of these will work for me.  The tooltip closes out as soon as the mouse leaves the target text.  I need it to persist so that users can copy/paste values from this popup.  And it looks like the popover element needs to be paired with a clickable button etc.

@tusharJadav I ended up going with a popover.  I'm using an information logo added as an additional column to the datatable.  When a user clicks the logo the popover opens and displays fields from the contact record.  Do you want to add your comment as an actual answer?  That way I can mark it as best answer.

Sure, I have added the comment as an answer.

You can use the lightning tooltip or create a custom popover component that can be triggered on mouseover events.
